# No community promotion ads any longer?

Tags: feature-request, policy

It seems there is no community promotion ads from 2021, so our community won't have that any longer? Different from some irrelevant commercial ads from the SE network, I in fact would like to see some community promotion ads, especially those with high score of votes. They are likely to be useful.

Comment: I was tempted to add the tag for [tag:community-ads], but only a moderator can do this.  It is intended to be used for posts that submit and vote on proposed community ads, but this might be worth reviewing it there is not future in those ads.  I rather liked them.  Some users (if I recall correctly) thought they were objectionable.

Comment: I found a discussion of irregularities in scheduling the Community Promotion Ad voting and display in [this 2021 Meta.SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360627/will-there-be-community-promotion-ads-in-2021-if-so-when).  Nothing there suggests to me that a decision was made to discontinue them, only that code changes were needed and led to some odd displays of dated ads.

Comment: A bit later than the post mentioned in the previous comment, this was posted on [meta.se]: [The future of Community Promotion, Open Source, and Hot Network Questions Ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364556).
When looking at other meta sites, there were community promotion ads [in 2021](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+is%3Aq+created:2021-01-01..), but I do not see anything [since 2022](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcommunity-ads%5D+is%3Aq+created:2022-01-01..).

Comment: @hardmath As the tag ([meta-tag:community-ads]) has a special meaning, would perhaps ([meta-tag:advertising]) be a reasonable approximation? (And, consequently, a suitable tag for this question.) [meta.se] has a separate tag ([community-promotion-ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-promotion-ads)) for discussing community ads - so another option would be creating a new tag, like on that site. (And this might be a reasonable name.)